# Why my Python match case does not insert into list?

Tags: python

My code(solving challenge)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    for _ in range(N):
        cmd, *args = input().split()
        data =[]
        match cmd:
            case "insert":
                data.insert(int(args[1]),args[0])
            case "print":
                print(data)
            case "remove":
                data.remove(args[0])
            case "append":
                data.append(args[0])
            case "sort":
                data.sort()
            case "reverse":
                data.reverse()
            case "pop":
                data.pop()
            case _:
                raise ValueError(f"Illegal command: {cmd}")
```

I run it

```
4 
append 1 
append 2
insert 3 1 
print
[]
```

and I have empty list.
How to fix empty list? Should I switch to `if elif` to prevent data resetting?

Comment: @DarkKnight I am practicing for Hacker Rank,if else version passes. But you are right,remarks are OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reassigning to your variable data on every loop. You should instead move  that assignment to before your loop eg.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
  N = int(input())
  data = [] # important part

  for _ in range(N):
    cmd, *args = input().split()
    # rest of code...
```